# Call using Skype from html without prompt window

Tags: html, skype

I have integrated skype call from html using

```
<a href"skype:+1**********">+1**********</a>
```

It initiates call but before that, there appears a prompt window which asks 'are you sure to want to continue'.

[image: skype prompt window]

Is there have any to call directly without any prompt window which can be initiated from html link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `<a href="tel:phoneNumber"></a>` instead. This has the added benefit of opening the Phone app on mobiles.